# Can Exchange 2007 SCR work between servers in different domains (same forest)?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, replication, domain

As per subject: if there is an Exchange 2007 server active in domain A, can another Exchange server in domain B (in the same forest, of course) be used as a Standby Continuous Replication (SCR) target for its databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, SCR targets must be in the same AD domain.

Comment: I'd assume exactly the same, but I need some confirmation on this issue.

Comment: http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2007/06/28/445538.aspx & http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/high-availability-recovery/managing-standby-continuous-replication-part1.html